# Upload the voice in particular name and format with user id phonegap

Tags: cordova, upload, voice-recording

I create one voice recording application following procedure from [Voice recording method from phonegap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_media_capture_capture.md.html#capture.captureAudio).

Once I record the voice and send to the server( http://{server}/{application}/myservice/register/) with some userid and audio file name as 'talk' and its send to wav format.How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

hi you can use phonegap FileTransfer  method. The FileTransfer object allows you to upload or download files to and from a server.
eg :

```
// !! Assumes variable fileURI contains a valid URI to a text file on the device

var win = function (r) {
console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
console.log("Response = " + r.response);
console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
}

var fail = function (error) {
alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
}

var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey = "file";
options.fileName = fileURI.substr(fileURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
options.mimeType = "text/plain";

var params = {};
params.value1 = "test";
params.value2 = "param";

options.params = params;

var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(fileURI, encodeURI("http://some.server.com/upload.php"), win, fail, options);
```

i think this may help you more info check [link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer)

Comment: in ios ? or android?, and check the default format of audio , i thnk default format is .amr ? i thnk for converting audio file to wav u need to write native plugins . no default methods in phonegap @SKM17

Comment: first u call  converter plugin (custom) and return the converted files path to js and upload that file

Comment: Ok I check the method